# Inline-Assembly : bad register name

Tags: c, gcc, inline-assembly

I get "Error: bad register name '%%ecx'" when compiling this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    asm("mov 3, %%ecx\n\t");
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using two percent signs? Also, any reason for the `\n\t`? This is not a printf format; those should not be needed.

Comment: What compiler? Inline assembler syntax is compiler dependent.

Comment: @mat http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s4

Comment: @Jongware I'm using gcc on windows 64-bit

Comment: @キューゾリファイ read the link you commented, and you will see it is not saying to end the string with `\n\t`! It's saying use that within a single `asm()` where you have _multiple_ instructions, and its example does _not_ use it at the end. Further, you do not see `%%` anywhere in that example. Other examples need it due to using an extended syntax which you are not using here.

Comment: @mah %% is for skipping %, and \n\t doesn't change anything

Comment: @キューゾリファイ : You're wrong about %. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @キューゾリファイ you're absolutely wrong (about the %) and it would have taken you less time to try it and see than it took you to argue it! Regarding the `\n\t` it's a no harm-but no help situation when you don't have multiple instructions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The double-percent sign for registers is used when you want to use gcc's "extended inline assembly", with input, output, and clobber lists. This is because the single-percent sign is reserved by the inline assembler for substituting actual operand names, based on these lists and the number after the `%`.

If you don't want to use the "extended" inline assembly, just use normal AT&T syntax. Doing something like this :

```
int main(void)
{
    asm("mov 3, %ecx\n\t");
    return 0;
}
```

Works perfectly fine with gcc 4.6.3. I'm also assuming that you know the difference between `mov 3, %ecx` and `mov $3, %ecx`.

Comment: In fact, I want to create a loop `int src = 1; int dst = 0; asm("mov $0x03, %ecx\n\trpt:\n\t\tnop\n\tloop rpt" : "=r" (dst) : "r" (src));` and now I'm getting `operand number missing after %-letter`

Comment: @キューゾリファイ when you use _extended_ format `asm()` (and **only** extended format) you must use `%%` on registers, and just a single `%` on operands. Read the link you commented previously!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I just started this yesterday night.